# React - pass props to specific child

Tags: reactjs

I have a Layout component as follows:

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react"
    import Navbar from "./Navbar"
    import "../styles/mains.scss"
     
     const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    
       return (
         <>
           <Navbar></Navbar>
           <main>
           {children}
           </main>
         </>
       )
     }
     export default Layout
```

I use Layout with some nested children in my Home component among other places:

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./layout";
import Header from "./Header";
import Work from "./Work";
import About from "./about";
import Footer from "./Footer";

  
export const Home = () => {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Header/>
        <Work/>
        <About/>
        <Footer/>
      </Layout>
  );
};
```

I now have a requirement that I pass props down into specific children. Specifically I need to pass a function into my child Work component. But I have no idea how to parse through the children and conditionally pass a function to a specific child component if it exists. Note that in many cases the Layout will not have the Work component as a child.

Comment: You can use React context

Comment: Another option: application store (with Redux or similar tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to have a clean contract between components. Notice here that this solution doesn't make any assumptions about your component tree besides requiring the `Layout` component being at the top, which makes the dependency between components much simpler.

Here is how you can apply on your example:

On your `Layout` component, use the Context API to pass values down the component tree, in this case, the function you want. I'm calling this function here as `doSomething`:

```
// file: layout.js
import { createContext, useCallback } from "react";

const LayoutContext = createContext();
LayoutContext.displayName = "LayoutContext";

export const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  
  // Here we use `useCallback` to make sure that
  // our function identity is the same between renders
  const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("do something from context");
  }, []);

  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={{ doSomething }}>
      <div>
        <h1>Layout header</h1>
        {children}
      </div>
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now you can create a custom hook that makes the use of this newly created context easier across components.

At the bottom of the `layout.js` file, add this:

```
import { useContext } from 'react'

export function useDoSomething() {
  const context = useContext(LayoutContext);

  // Here we check if the context is available
  // otherwise, it's probably due to the `Layout`
  // component not being on the top of the component tree.
  if (typeof context === "undefined") {
    throw new Error(
      "doSomething is not available on your component tree" +
       "\n" +
       "Make sure to use `Layout` before using `useDoSomething` hook"
    );
  }
  return context;
}
```

Now on your `Work` component, you can use our newly created custom hook to grab the function you need.

```
// file: work.js
import { Layout, useDoSomething } from "./Layout";

export const Work = () => {
  
  // Here you can consume the context via our
  // custom hook.
  const { doSomething } = useDoSomething();

  doSomething();

  return <h1>Work component</h1>;
};
```

And here is how the top level component could look like:

```
// file: app.js
import {Layout} from './layout'
import {Work} from './work'
 
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Work />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of my reputation.
What about passing props on demand on the parents?
If you would like to conditionally add a prop for the layout's childrens, I would go for a React.cloneElement() approach like this:

```
 {
    React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, ...(child.props.id === 'workID' && {
        propToBeAdded
      }))
    )
  }
```

So, you'll need to add and id to the Work component.

```
<Work id="workID" />
```

Despite it's possible (I haven't tried out the code for a fast response, let me know if I'm missing something), I wouldn't do this, are you reusing it EVERYWHERE? It feels like a smell.

Comment: Felipe, I don't think your solution is optimal, but you get my upvote for audacity :)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRovinsky. I don't think either, but I tried to provide the solution for his use case, I would go for Context API, Redux or prop drilling if it's not getting shared across multiple components. (Lately I was forced to use cloneElement in a messy way, it felt bad, but was necessary).